# Poor performance to SELECT and UPDATE one million rows in Oracle via JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, batch-processing

I have a user table (Oracle 11g DB) with more than 1 million rows which has all the user passwords in plain text which I am trying to hash using SHA512 algorithm (hash and salt). To start with below is my Java class to read all the records from user table, hash it and update back to user table.

- I am using prepared statement for both **SELECT** and **UPDATE** queries
- I have set the prepared statement fetch size to 1000 (`setFetchSize(1000)`)
- I have set the auto commit property to false
- Using batch method to do bulk update

```
try {
    ps = con.prepareStatement("update user set password=? where ID=?");
    psSel = con.prepareStatement("select ID, password from user");
    psSel.setFetchSize(1000);
    rs = psSel.executeQuery();
    String hashPassword = null;
    while (rs.next()) {
        long id = rs.getLong(1);
        String pwd = rs.getString(2);
        hashPassword = <<CALL TO PASSWORD HASHING UTIL>>;
        ps.setString(1, hashPassword);
        ps.setLong(2, id);
        ps.addBatch();

      //Every 5000 records update and commit
        if(++count % batchSize == 0) {
            ps.executeBatch();
            con.commit();
        }

    }
    ps.executeBatch();
    con.commit();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To update 100,000 records the above method takes close to 8 minutes which I feel is quite high.

**Database used:** Oracle 11g

**Java Version:** 1.6

**Environment:** Windows 7

I am not sure if I am missing something. Can you advise or recommend any best way to process such bulk loads?

## UPDATE

I took a second look at the temp table - **USER** I created before and could see there was no **Primary Key constraint** added to the ID column. I went ahead and added the PK constraint for ID column and re ran my utility. Now it just took **36 seconds** to process **100,000 rows**.

To be double sure I also created another temp table **USER_TMP2** without PK constraint and ran my utility and it took **8 mins** as usual for **100,000**

Comment: 8 min to **hash** and update in DB 1 million records doesn't seem high

Comment: Are you able to replicate your hash function on the database side? You could do a single update if so, without having to move all the data across the network to and from Java. It isn't clear where the bottleneck is here though.

Comment: Why not use the `HASH_SH512` in `DBMS_CRYPTO`?

Comment: did you do ANY basic debugging, like profiling the code? for all you know the DB stuff is taking 0.1 seconds, and the other 7 minutes 59.9 seconds is spent in your hash function.

Comment: @ppeterka - I am using Oracle 11g database and it lacks SHA512 support

Comment: @RC. . I tried for 1 lakh records which took 8 min. So for 1 million it might take more time i believe.

Comment: Oh I got confused by "lakh", so yeah time might be an issue, How about this crazy idea: install on some VM a version of oracle supporting the hash you want, dump your data, insert into the VM, select/update, dump and put back the updated data in the old oracle ?

Comment: @Sachin - you could write a Java Stored Procedure that uses Java's hashing capabilities but runs in the DB, That assumes the salt is available to the DB of course. And that the network trips are actually the bottleneck.

Comment: @Sachin Sorry, I falsely remembered that it supports it...

Comment: @AlexPoole can you provide some sample reference for this approach.

Comment: Did you measure how long a SHA512 hashing call takes? 4.8 ms per row seems a bit too slow for me. Are you running this remotely or on the machine where Oracle is installed? The latter should be faster.

Comment: Not for hashing specifically; but [start with the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e10588/chfive.htm#JJDEV13237). But, again, debug to find out where the bottleneck really is. Also, presumably this is a one-off process; do you really need it to be much faster?

Comment: @StefanZobel No i haven't measured the hashing time, i just measured the total time taken to execute the whole process. For hashing i am using MessageDigest class and the oracle db is not installed in my local machine.

Comment: You should do that. It's important to know how much of these 4.8 ms can be assigned to the databae roundtrips. If you have Java installed on the DB server it would be a good idea to run your batch on the DB server (it's a one-time action after all). Anyway, 4.8 ms is too slow if your network is halfway decent. How far away from you is the DB server?

Comment: Presumably this is a one time operation so is it worth spending time optimising it? If you do need to run this multiple times then the first thing to do is to install a profile and see what's really taking the time. Assuming the delay is on the Oracle side, consider creating a new table, copying the data to the new table (with the hashed password) and then dropping the old table. You could also look at using SQL*Loader to do the inserts.

Comment: Additionally, any DB `TRIGGER`s that are specified to execute before/after update of the `USER` table will slow down the operation. If such exist, consider disabling them while the bulk update is executing.

Comment: @StefanZobel I just wrote a test method to see how long my Password Hashing operation takes. It took on an average 1.5 seconds for 100,000 loops.

Comment: What's the value of `batchSize`? And what transaction isolation level do you use?

Comment: @AndrewLygin BatchSize is 5000. Transaction isolation is  TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED, i guess that is the default value.

Comment: So the problem was just that the update was having to do a full table scan, because there was no index (via a PK or otherwise) on the ID column?

Comment: @AlexPoole yeah, post adding PK on the ID column, the utility ran in 35 seconds for 100,000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

> I took a second look at the temp table - USER I created before and could see there was no Primary Key constraint added to the ID column. I went ahead and added the PK constraint for ID column and re ran my utility. Now it just took 36 seconds to process 100,000 rows.
>
> To be double sure I also created another temp table USER_TMP2 without PK constraint and ran my utility and it took 8 mins as usual for 100,000

Moral of the story: When investigating poor performance the **first thing** to do is investigate the indexing of the tables involved – either by simple inspection or by looking at the execution plans of the queries – to ensure that you are not doing a lot of unnecessary table scans.

Answer (score -1):

Make a view of user table, and fetch the data from that table. This will optimize your query execution time. It might be helpful in your case.

Comment: Nothing about creating a view will optimise the query execution